# How to select a number from an array with given probability distribution

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random

I want to select a number from a list with a given probability.

I use numpy and I have defined a list to choose from. I also have a probability distribution matching the entries of my list.

```
from numpy import random

a = [0, 1]     # select one entry from this list
p = [0.0, 1.0] # probability distribution
print(random.choice(a, 1, p))
```

With the distribution `p` I should only receive 1. However, when I run my code, I receive 0 too often. I think my distribution doesn't really affect the selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `numpy.random.choice`:

> choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)

When you call `choice(a, 1, p)`, the third positional argument `p` is used for the `replace` parameter<sup>1</sup>, not for the `p` parameter as you intend.

You either need to insert another positional argument for `replace`, so that `p` becomes the fourth positional argument:

```
choice(a, 1, True, p)
```

or explicitly pass `p` as a keyword argument:

```
choice(a, 1, p=p)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This works because a list can also be evaluated in a boolean context. In this case, `[0.0, 1.0]`, as a non-empty list, would be evaluated as `True`.